# Spatial Join in Python Field Mapping with Multiple Merge Rules

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join, python-toolbox, field-mapping

I'm performing a Spatial Join with a polygon (target) and a point (joinFeature)- which has 5 fields in it that I need to "sum". I have written a Spatial Join and (after many long days) gotten the field mapping to work! But this time is different because I am using a Merge Rule.

Here is my code, right now it breaks at the spatial join and outputs an empty feature class.

Also, this is in a Python Toolbox and uses Parameters to get the target and joinFeature. Like I said, I have gotten this to work before without a merge rule and with different fields...

```
        # Create a new fieldmappings and add the two input feature classes.
        fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()
        fms.addTable(target)
        fms.addTable(joinFeature)

        # Create the required FieldMap and FieldMappings objects
        fm_apt_poly_APT_ID = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fm_stud_ELEM = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fm_stud_INT = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fm_stud_MID = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fm_stud_HIGH = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fm_stud_TOT_STUD = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()

        # Get the field names for both original files
        apt_poly_APT_ID = "APT_ID"
        stud_ELEM = "ELEM"
        stud_INT = "INT"
        stud_MID = "MID"
        stud_HIGH = "HIGH"
        stud_TOT_STUD = "TOT_STUD"

        # Add fields to their corresponding FieldMap objects
        fm_apt_poly_APT_ID.addInputField(target, "APT_ID")
        fm_stud_ELEM.addInputField(joinFeature, "ELEM")
        fm_stud_INT.addInputField(joinFeature, "INT")
        fm_stud_MID.addInputField(joinFeature, "MID")
        fm_stud_HIGH.addInputField(joinFeature, "HIGH")
        fm_stud_TOT_STUD.addInputField(joinFeature, "TOT_STUD")

        # Set the output field properties for both FieldMap objects
        apt_poly_APT_ID = fm_apt_poly_APT_ID.outputField
        apt_poly_APT_ID.name = "APT_ID"
        fm_apt_poly_APT_ID.outputField = apt_poly_APT_ID

        stud_ELEM = fm_stud_ELEM.outputField
        stud_ELEM.name = "ELEM"
        stud_ELEM.aliasName = "ELEM"
        fm_stud_ELEM.outputField = stud_ELEM

        stud_INT = fm_stud_ELEM.outputField
        stud_INT.name = "INT"
        stud_INT.aliasName = "INT"
        fm_stud_INT.outputField = stud_INT

        stud_MID = fm_stud_MID.outputField
        stud_MID.name = "MID"
        stud_MID.aliasName = "MID"
        fm_stud_MID.outputField = stud_MID

        stud_HIGH = fm_stud_HIGH.outputField
        stud_HIGH.name = "HIGH"
        stud_HIGH.aliasName = "HIGH"
        fm_stud_HIGH.outputField = stud_HIGH

        stud_TOT_STUD = fm_stud_TOT_STUD.outputField
        stud_TOT_STUD.name = "TOT_STUD"
        stud_TOT_STUD.aliasName = "TOT_STUD"
        fm_stud_TOT_STUD.outputField = stud_TOT_STUD

        # Set the merge rule to sum and then replace the old field map in the mappings object with the updated one
        fm_stud_ELEM.mergeRule = "SUM"
        fm_stud_INT.mergeRule = "SUM"
        fm_stud_MID.mergeRule = "SUM"
        fm_stud_HIGH.mergeRule = "SUM"
        fm_stud_TOT_STUD.mergeRule = "SUM"
        fms.addFieldMap(fm_apt_poly_APT_ID)
        fms.addFieldMap(fm_stud_ELEM)
        fms.addFieldMap(fm_stud_INT)
        fms.addFieldMap(fm_stud_MID)
        fms.addFieldMap(fm_stud_HIGH)
        fms.addFieldMap(fm_stud_TOT_STUD)

        # Spatial Join Sample Code
        # SpatialJoin_analysis (target_features, join_features, out_feature_class, {join_operation}, {join_type}, {field_mapping}, {match_option}, {search_radius}, {distance_field_name})
        # Process: Spatial Join
        arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target, joinFeature, output, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL", fms, "", "INTERSECT", "")
        arcpy.AddMessage("Just performed Spatial Join")
```

Comment: I should note that if I use the replaceFieldMap function like I have found in some of my help research, I get null values in my fields in my output and the TOT_STUD is twice as much as the sum... No idea how that happens!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For any coding questions we ask you to only present a snippet that shows where you are stuck.  Although you are only showing the one tool class, I think it should be possible and helpful for you to try to reduce that some more to just the parts we really need to see.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Potential answerers do not always read the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem is a frustrating one but it works so i'm ok with it. I ended up deleting all of the fields in my target and join feature except the ones that I needed to keep. Then field mapped those with a merge rule of "Sum" (see below) and then performed a table join, two field calculations and changed Null values to 0. Here is my code that works:

```
    # Copy features to a new layer
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(target,outputfeatureAPT,config_keyword="#",spatial_grid_1="0",spatial_grid_2="0",spatial_grid_3="0")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(joinFeatureSTUD,outputfeatureSTUD,config_keyword="#",spatial_grid_1="0",spatial_grid_2="0",spatial_grid_3="0")

    # Delete fields in copy features before you spatial join
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(outputfeatureAPT,drop_field="APT;ADDRESS;PA;TYPE;STATUS;LIU;MRU;UNITS;CLASS;LOW_INCOME;APP_NUM;ELEM;INT_;MID;HIGH;ELEM_STUD;INT_STUD;MID_STUD;HIGH_STUD;TOT_STUD;ELEM_YLD;INT_YLD;MID_YLD;HIGH_YLD;TOT_YLD;LAST_EDIT;NOTES")

    # The following inputs are layers or table views: "stud_0915_1"
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(outputfeatureSTUD,drop_field="Loc_name;Status;Score;Match_type;X;Y;Match_addr;Side;Pct_along;ARC_Street;ARC_Zip;ARC_City;ARC_Postal;ISD;STUD_ID;NAME;F_NAME;L_NAME;ADDRESS;ZIP;CITY;CAMPUS_ID;SCHOOL;GRADE;ETHNICITY;ED;BIL;PA;RESIDE;CLASS;SUB;EE_PK;EE;PK;KG;GRD1;GRD2;GRD3;GRD4;GRD5;GRD6;GRD7;GRD8;GRD9;GRD10;GRD11;GRD12;AMER_IND;ASIAN;BLACK;HISPANIC;WHITE;PACIFIC;MULTI;BIL_EE;BIL_PK;BIL_KG;BIL_GRD1;BIL_GRD2;BIL_GRD3;BIL_GRD4;BIL_GRD5;BIL_GRD6;BIL_ELEM;BIL_INT;BIL_MID;BIL_HIGH;ED_ELEM;ED_INT;ED_MID;ED_HIGH;AMER_IND_ELEM;AMER_IND_INT;AMER_IND_MID;AMER_IND_HIGH;ASIAN_ELEM;ASIAN_INT;ASIAN_MID;ASIAN_HIGH;BLACK_ELEM;BLACK_INT;BLACK_MID;BLACK_HIGH;HISPANIC_ELEM;HISPANIC_INT;HISPANIC_MID;HISPANIC_HIGH;WHITE_ELEM;WHITE_INT;WHITE_MID;WHITE_HIGH;PACIFIC_ELEM;PACIFIC_INT;PACIFIC_MID;PACIFIC_HIGH;MULTI_ELEM;MULTI_INT;MULTI_MID;MULTI_HIGH;SF;MF;EXEMPT_65;RENTER")

    # Create a new fieldmappings and add the two input feature classes.
    fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()
    fms.addTable(outputfeatureAPT)
    fms.addTable(outputfeatureSTUD)
    ELEMSumIndex = fms.findFieldMapIndex("ELEM")
    INT_SumIndex = fms.findFieldMapIndex("INT_")
    MIDSumIndex = fms.findFieldMapIndex("MID")
    HIGHSumIndex = fms.findFieldMapIndex("HIGH")
    TOT_STUDSumIndex = fms.findFieldMapIndex("TOT_STUD")

    # Create the required FieldMap and FieldMappings objects
    fm_apt_poly_APT_ID = arcpy.FieldMap()
    fm_stud_ELEM = fms.getFieldMap(ELEMSumIndex)
    fm_stud_INT_ = fms.getFieldMap(INT_SumIndex)
    fm_stud_MID = fms.getFieldMap(MIDSumIndex)
    fm_stud_HIGH = fms.getFieldMap(HIGHSumIndex)
    fm_stud_TOT_STUD = fms.getFieldMap(TOT_STUDSumIndex)
    fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()

    # Create the required FieldMap and FieldMappings objects
    fm_apt_poly_APT_ID = arcpy.FieldMap()
    fm_stud_ELEM = arcpy.FieldMap()
    fm_stud_INT_ = arcpy.FieldMap()
    fm_stud_MID = arcpy.FieldMap()
    fm_stud_HIGH = arcpy.FieldMap()
    fm_stud_TOT_STUD = arcpy.FieldMap()
    fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()

    # Get the field names for both original files
    apt_poly_APT_ID = "APT_ID"
    stud_ELEM = "ELEM"
    stud_INT_ = "INT_"
    stud_MID = "MID"
    stud_HIGH = "HIGH"
    stud_TOT_STUD = "TOT_STUD"

    # Add fields to their corresponding FieldMap objects
    fm_apt_poly_APT_ID.addInputField(outputfeatureAPT, "APT_ID")
    fm_stud_ELEM.addInputField(outputfeatureSTUD, "ELEM")
    fm_stud_INT_.addInputField(outputfeatureSTUD, "INT_")
    fm_stud_MID.addInputField(outputfeatureSTUD, "MID")
    fm_stud_HIGH.addInputField(outputfeatureSTUD, "HIGH")
    fm_stud_TOT_STUD.addInputField(outputfeatureSTUD, "TOT_STUD")

    # Set the output field properties for both FieldMap objects
    apt_poly_APT_ID = fm_apt_poly_APT_ID.outputField
    apt_poly_APT_ID.name = "APT_ID"
    fm_apt_poly_APT_ID.outputField = apt_poly_APT_ID

    stud_ELEM = fm_stud_ELEM.outputField
    stud_ELEM.name = "ELEM"
    stud_ELEM.aliasName = "ELEM"
    fm_stud_ELEM.outputField = stud_ELEM

    stud_INT_ = fm_stud_ELEM.outputField
    stud_INT_.name = "INT_"
    stud_INT_.aliasName = "INT_"
    fm_stud_INT_.outputField = stud_INT_

    stud_MID = fm_stud_MID.outputField
    stud_MID.name = "MID"
    stud_MID.aliasName = "MID"
    fm_stud_MID.outputField = stud_MID

    stud_HIGH = fm_stud_HIGH.outputField
    stud_HIGH.name = "HIGH"
    stud_HIGH.aliasName = "HIGH"
    fm_stud_HIGH.outputField = stud_HIGH

    stud_TOT_STUD = fm_stud_TOT_STUD.outputField
    stud_TOT_STUD.name = "TOT_STUD"
    stud_TOT_STUD.aliasName = "TOT_STUD"
    fm_stud_TOT_STUD.outputField = stud_TOT_STUD

    # Set the merge rule to sum and then replace the old field map in the mappings object with the updated one
    fm_stud_ELEM.mergeRule = "SUM"
    fm_stud_INT_.mergeRule = "SUM"
    fm_stud_MID.mergeRule = "SUM"
    fm_stud_HIGH.mergeRule = "SUM"
    fm_stud_TOT_STUD.mergeRule = "SUM"
    fms.addFieldMap(fm_apt_poly_APT_ID)
    fms.addFieldMap(fm_stud_ELEM)
    fms.addFieldMap(fm_stud_INT_)
    fms.addFieldMap(fm_stud_MID)
    fms.addFieldMap(fm_stud_HIGH)
    fms.addFieldMap(fm_stud_TOT_STUD)

    # Spatial Join Sample Code
    # SpatialJoin_analysis (target_features, join_features, out_feature_class, {join_operation}, {join_type}, {field_mapping}, {match_option}, {search_radius}, {distance_field_name})
    # Process: Spatial Join
    arcpy.AddMessage("Performing Student Spatial Join")
    arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(outputfeatureAPT, outputfeatureSTUD, output2, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL", fms, "INTERSECT", "", "")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Just performed Student Spatial Join")

    # Join the output to your apt_poly_xxxx by the APT_ID field
    # JoinField_management Sample Code
    # arcpy.JoinField_management(Input Feature, "Field Name", "join table", "join field", {["fields"]})
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(target, "APT_ID", output2, "APT_ID","")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Just performed Student Table Join")

    # Calculate Field_management Sample Code
    # arcpy.CalculateField_management(Input Feature, "Field Name", expression, "expression type", code block)

    # Process: Calculate Field, with a string index in the expression used to isolate the feature class name
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(target, targetname + ".ELEM_STUD", '!'+output2[74:]+'.ELEM!', "PYTHON_9.3")
    # Process: Calculate Field (2)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(target, targetname + ".INT_STUD", '!'+output2[74:]+'.INT_!', "PYTHON_9.3")
    # Process: Calculate Field (3)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(target, targetname + ".MID_STUD", '!'+output2[74:]+'.MID!', "PYTHON_9.3")
    # Process: Calculate Field (4)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(target, targetname + ".HIGH_STUD", '!'+output2[74:]+'.HIGH!', "PYTHON_9.3")
    # Process: Calculate Field (5)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(target, targetname + ".TOT_STUD", '!'+output2[74:]+'.TOT_STUD!', "PYTHON_9.3")

    # Remove the Join
    arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(target, "")

    # Process: Calculate Field
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(target, "ELEM_YLD", "[ELEM_STUD] / [UNITS]", "VB", "")
    # Process: Calculate Field (2)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(target, "INT_YLD", "[INT_STUD]/ [UNITS]", "VB", "")
    # Process: Calculate Field (3)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(target, "MID_YLD", "[MID_STUD]/ [UNITS]", "VB", "")
    # Process: Calculate Field (4)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(target, "HIGH_YLD", "[HIGH_STUD]/ [UNITS]", "VB", "")
    # Process: Calculate Field (5)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(target, "TOT_YLD", "[TOT_STUD]/ [UNITS]", "VB", "")


    arcpy.AddMessage("Changing Null values to 0")

    # Update Null values in the calculated fields
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(target, ("ELEM_STUD","INT_STUD","MID_STUD","HIGH_STUD","TOT_STUD","ELEM_YLD","INT_YLD","MID_YLD","HIGH_YLD","TOT_YLD")) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            newrow = [0 if x == None else x for x in row]
            cursor.updateRow(newrow)

    del row

    return
```